# Java encoding - corrupted French characters

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have a system, where I got French Text from third party, but I am facing hard time to get it readable.

```
String frenchReceipt = "RETIRï¿½E"; // The original Text should be "RETIRÉE"
```

I tried all possible combinations to convert the string using encoding of UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1

```
String frenchReceipt = "RETIRï¿½E"; // The original Text should be "RETIRÉE"

byte[] b1 = new String(frenchReceipt.getBytes()).getBytes("UTF-8"); 
System.out.println(new String(b1));  // RETIRÃ¯Â¿Â½E

byte[] b2 = new String(frenchReceipt.getBytes()).getBytes("ISO-8859-1"); 
System.out.println(new String(b2));  // RETIRï¿½E

byte[] b3 = new String(frenchReceipt.getBytes(), "UTF-8").getBytes(); 
System.out.println(new String(b3));  // RETIR?E 

byte[] b4 = new String(frenchReceipt.getBytes(), "UTF-8").getBytes(); 
System.out.println(new String(b4));  //RETIR?E

byte[] b5 = new String(frenchReceipt.getBytes(), "ISO-8859-1").getBytes("UTF-8"); 
System.out.println(new String(b5));  //RETIRÃ¯Â¿Â½E

byte[] b6 = new String(frenchReceipt.getBytes(), "UTF-8").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"); 
System.out.println(new String(b6));  //RETIR?E

byte[] b7 = new String(frenchReceipt.getBytes(), "UTF-8").getBytes("UTF-8"); 
System.out.println(new String(b7));  //RETIRï¿½E

byte[] b8 = new String(frenchReceipt.getBytes(), "ISO-8859-1").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"); 
System.out.println(new String(b8));  //RETIRï¿½E
```

As you see nothing fix the problem.

Please advise.

**Update:**
The third -party partner confirmed that data sent to my application in "ISO-8859-1" Encoding

Comment: What encoding has the console the System.out is going to?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543548/whats-going-on-with-this-byte-array. The characters ï¿½ are encoded as EF BF BD, what is mentioned there in the answer.

Comment: @mayamar Default text file encoding is: "Cp1252". But I tried to change it also "UTF-8" and "ISO-8859-1" but it didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ï¿½ is just a replacement character (`EF|BF|BD` UTF-8) and used to indicate problems when a system is unable to render a correct symbol.
It means that you have no chance to convert ï¿½ into É.

`frenchReceipt` doesn't contain any byte sequence which could be converted into É because of the declaration:

```java
String frenchReceipt = "RETIRï¿½E";
```

Your code snippet below should work pretty fine but you have to use the correct byte source.

```java
byte[] b2 = new String(frenchReceipt.getBytes()).getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
System.out.println(new String(b2));
```

So if you read "RETIRÉE" by bytes from a data source and get `52|45|54|49|52|C9|45` (ISO-8859-1 is expected) then you'll get the proper result.
If the data source has already the byte sequence `EF|BF|BD` the only option you have is search&replace, but in this case, there is no difference between i.e. ä and É.

**Update**:
Since the data are delivered by TCP

```java
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(),"ISO-8859-1"))
```

solved the issue.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what should I do?  I didn't understand last part of your answer. Ho to  read "RETIRÉE" by bytes from data source and get 52|45|54|49|52|C9|45  ??

Comment: The answer on the question "how to read" depends on the data source
(XML, database, binary stream, etc). What is the real data source of "RETIRï¿½E"?

Comment: According to the document it is "plain text" encoded as "ISO-8859-1"

Comment: To make it clear: the response I got is series of parameters separated Field Separator (FS) and ends with (EOT) Field. For example: 00[FS]RETIRï¿½E[FS]FR[EOT] Of course there is no brackets [ ] for FS and EOT, just added to be more readable

Comment: I asked about data source to make clear the reason why some characters are lost.
Is it the trouble of rendering or the data source has already corrupted?
So the question is still open for me. If it were the "plain text" encoded as "ISO-8859-1" you would solve the issue easily.

Comment: As far as I can guess you are working with HTTP response.
The best option here is encoding the record 00[FS]RETIRÉE[FS]FR[EOT] with base64 on server side and decode on the client. In this case you will have no troubles with "unrecognized" characters.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538021/why-do-we-use-base64
Also if you are dealing with HTTP try to ask the server to encode response headers.put("Accept-Encoding", "UTF-8");headers.put("Accept-Encoding", "UTF-8");

Comment: If it is just a file please open the record in any hex editor and make sure that the sequence EF|BF|BD is not present there. It is not easy to help without real data snipped.

Comment: It is not HTTP, but I connect to the server via TCP protocol, and I am using persistent socket open/close for every request and response. and in the response I got string parameter as the sample I send before: 00[FS]RETIRï¿½E[FS]FR[EOT]

Comment: TCP connection has no concept of char encoding. Try to read the stream with
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(),"ISO-8859-1"));

Comment: Thanks a lot. That exactly what I was asking for. It fix the issue