# File upload issue in aspnet core

Tags: asp.net, .net, file-upload

I'm facing a strange issue with handling file upload in aspnet core using .net6. I'm working with REST api and implemented uploading of binary files. I need just to save binary files from the request to the folder on server. For reading files from request and saving them I use the code like that:

```
await Request.Body.CopyToAsync(stream,...)
```

The problem it that when I'm checking Request.Body it contains more bytes than original file. When saving contents of Request.Body to the file, the created file contains a lot of additional "ef bf bd" bytes so the original file is broken. How these "ef bf bd" bytes arrive in the request body?

Comment: Based on the answer to this question, it is because your file is not encoded in the same standard it is being decoded with. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543548/whats-going-on-with-this-byte-array

Comment: "ef bf bd" is the UTF8 replacement character, so something is going funny with encoding somewhere. Are you stringifying it somehow?

Comment: You are both right. The issue was caused by middleware in which original BufferedStream of request body was replaced with MemoryStream with UTF-8 encoding, so all binary data in request body was corrupted. Thanks)